# Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined in meteor.JS function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following code:

```
Template.analyze.userFullName = function() {
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {name: 1}});
    return u.profile.name;
};
```

`Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {name: 1}})` returns the following when used in the console:

```
Object
    _id: "79ef0e67-6611-4747-b669-45cc163cc1d8"
    profile: Object
        name: "My Name"
```

But when I use it in code above I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`

Why is this happening?  All I want to do is retrieve the user's full name in their profile and pass it to a template part.

Comment: I'm assuming that however you're fetching the users collection, it's not finished getting the data from the server by the time that `Template.analyze.userFullName` is called.

Comment: @Vinay I'm fetching the users collection with the publish and subscribe functions.  How should I check that it's finished downloading before retrieving it?

Comment: Take a look at `observe`: http://docs.meteor.com/#observe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Template is being rendered immediately on pageload when the user is not available yet, which is causing an error. Thankfully since you're using the Users collection, which is reactive, you can just have it re-render when it becomes available. You do this by checking first if the object is not null:

```
Template.analyze.userFullName = function() {
    // use Meteor.user() since it's available
    if (Meteor.user())
      return Meteor.user().profile.name;
};
```

This way, when the user is null (during load) the Template won't throw an error. Immediately upon the data being available, the reactivity will invoke the template again, and it will render on the screen.

Comment: Rahul, you're amazing.  Thanks for all the help with Meteor!

Comment: Here's an interesting error.  If I start from logged out state, then login, the app recognizes that and changes the page, and it works fine.  But if I refresh while logged in, it throws the error again.

Comment: Nevermind, simply adding `if ( ! Meteor.loggingIn())` check before the return solves the problem.