# Meteor Router Route Property Undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a route set up like this:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/:menuSlug': function(menuSlug) {
        Template.menu.items = function() { return Items.find({menuId: Menus.findOne({slug: menuSlug})._id}); }
        return 'menu';
    }
});
```

However, when I browse to /my-test-slug, I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

I think that this is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107148/979315 but since I am not using the Meteor.user() reactive collection, I am not sure how to re-render this page once the data is fetched appropriately. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you checked the content of menuSlug? 
or it might be that the Menu entry does not exist.

Comment: The menu entry does exist. The page loads before the data is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to seperate the template helper from the router code and use a Session hash to store the message:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/:menuSlug': function(menuSlug) {
        Session.set("menuslug", menuSlug);
        return 'menu';
    }
});

Template.menu.items = function() {
    var item = Menus.findOne({slug: menuSlug});
    if(item) return Items.find({menuId: item._id});
});
```

The other issue might be that the data is sent down later. So for a while there might not be any data (particularly if you load the URI straight to the page). So you need to account for the situation where there may be no data in the local collection yet.

Comment: I think you meant var item = Menus.findOne({slug: Session.get('menuSlug')});

Comment: When I tried this, it loads the page but the template is missing the data (so no error, which is progress). So how do I make this session variable reactive so it loads in the template as soon as the data gets fetched appropriately?

Comment: If you use the 'Session' hashes via set/get it will automatically be reactive. If it doesn't theres probably an issue with missing Menus or missing Items. Post back whats in your collection. (which you can check by running Menus.find().fetch() and Items.find().fetch in your js console